# XHTML tab system

Tags: tabs, xhtml

I'm designing a webpage that uses a tab-system for the user to advance through steps of a tutorial. There is some content at the top of the page, so users need to scroll down a bit to get to the tabs / tutorial. When I click each tab, the page re-loads and shifts to the top of the screen, making the user scroll back down for each section. Is there an easy way to set the browsers position to line up with the tabs to avoid this annoying behavior?

Comment: Solved: I used a simple JavaScript to calculate a position of an element on the screen. I edited my original post to include source code...

Comment: You can also write your solution as an answer and explain it a bit more for somebody else to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I call the below javascript function after the page is loaded. It will simply scroll the browser to the top boundry of the target element.

```
function scrollToPosition() {
    var boundingrect = document.getElementById("content").getBoundingClientRect();
    window.scrollBy(0,boundingrect.top); 
}
```